# Android to PC data exchange via Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a Java desktop application acting like "server" and an Android application, that should be acting as a "client".
"Client" should send String and receive response String[] from "server". The only method, I've came across is using Sockets like this

```
Socket socket = null;
    try {
        Log.d(log_tag, "creating socket");
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.123", 8090);
        Log.d(log_tag, "creating out");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Log.d(log_tag, "out created. sending data");
        out.writeUTF("sql");
        Log.d(log_tag, "data sent");
        Log.d(log_tag, "receiving data. loop");
        while(in.available() == 0);
        Log.d(log_tag, "received = " + in.readUTF());
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        Log.d(log_tag, "all closed");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(log_tag, "finished");
```

"Server" is built the same way, except for order of operations(first read, then write response).

**The problem**: Android application freezes on line

```
while(in.available() == 0);
```

so, InputStream never gets ready and I can't receive server response, but "server" reports, that the data was sent.
Can you point me to my mistake(it's obvious one, I suppose, but I can't see it)?
P.S. Maybe that's the wrong way, but it's not an option to use any mid-layers here. I can't modify server code too.

Comment: First, make sure your device/emulator can see 192.168.1.123 at all. For example, if you are running in the emulator, and 192.168.1.123 is the development machine hosting the emulator, 192.168.1.123 may not work -- you should be using 10.0.2.2 instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Ip address is ok - tested by creating simple server socket application on the development machine. Data was successfully received and response string was sent. However, android application still stuck on receiving response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of necropost :)

The problem was in the "server" code.

In my case it was sending empty UTF string, which can't be received at all(should be at least one space character for InputStream to catch something)